# Compiler and Interpreter

Tags: php, compilation, interpreter

How compiler or interpreter is using in PHP. Can any one explain.

Comment: yes because JVM can have JIT and AOT compilers as well interpreter also

Comment: Are you in the middle of an exam?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that ,

> Interpretor is the part of JVM

And also JVM has,

1. A virtual processor
2. Just-In-Time(JIT) compiler

which interpretor doesnt have.

what both does ,

**JVM:** *It is a specification that provides runtime environment in which java bytecode can be executed.*

**Interpreter**: *Read bytecode stream then execute the instructions.*